# How to escape slashes in Perl text used in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl, escaping, slash

```
end_date=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y")
/usr/bin/perl -pi -e "s/_end_date_/${end_date}/g" filename
```

I want to replace string '_end_date_' with the current date. Since the current date has slashes in it (yes, I want the slashes), I need to escape them. How can I do this?

I've tried several ways, like replacing slashes with "/" using [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) and Perl itself, but it didn't work. Finally I used 'cut' to break date in 3 parts and escaped slashes, but this solution doesn't look good. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Perl you can choose which character to use to separate parts of a regular expression. The following code will work fine.

```
end_date = $(date +"%m/%d/%Y")
/usr/bin/perl -pi -e "s#_end_date_#${end_date}#g" filename
```

This is to avoid the 'leaning toothpick' syndrome with / alternating.

Answer (score 6):

Use a different `s` delimiter: `s{all/the/slashes/you/want/}{replacement}`.

Answer (score 1):

I *would* recommend changing the delimiter, but you can almost always get by with quotemeta:

```
/usr/bin/perl -pi -e "my \$ed=quotemeta('${end_date}');s/_end_date_/\$ed/g" filename
```

But you also have this route:

```
/usr/bin/perl -pi -e 'BEGIN { use POSIX qw<strftime>; $ed=quotemeta(strftime( q[%m/%d/%Y], localtime())); } s/_end_date_/$ed/'
```

which does the same thing as your two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Axeman's answer, the following works for me :

```
 perl -MPOSIX=strftime  -p -e'$ed=strftime( q[%m/%d/%Y], localtime()) ;s/_end_date_/$ed/'
```

A few things to note

- The quotemeta isn't needed because the compiler isn't looking for a `/` in the variable `$ed`.
- I have used single quotes `'` rather than `"` as otherwise you end up having to quote `$`
- I prefer using  `-MPOSIX=strftime` to `BEGIN { use POSIX qw<strftime> }`